# Adding/Editing MYSQL keys

Tags: mysql, database

I am working on a table within a MySQL database that has the following columns:

```
 - ItemID (auto incremented key)
 - Item
 - CategoryID (empty column)
 - Category
 - SubcategoryID (empty column)
 - Subcategory
```

In other tables within the same database I have a list of categories and subcategories with their unique IDs, and I would like to take those IDs from the existing tables and port them over to the item table I described above.  After porting the IDs over, I intend to delete the category and subcategory entries, as the ID will serve as enough reference for my purposes.

I could do this manually, and I will do it manually if necessary, but going through several thousand entries in MySQL doesn't sound like my ideal afternoon.

My question is simply, is there a way to use my existing tables to alter my item table (above) in the way I described?

Thanks!

Comment: mysql supports joins in updates:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Comment: I assume those are *columns*, not *categories*?

Comment: That's correct, I got careless on my wording there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a `category` table with an `id` and `category` field and the `category` field matches `items.category` table.

To update the `items.category_id`, JOIN to the `category` table on `items.category <=> category.category` and UPDATE `items.category_id` with value in `category.id`

```
UPDATE items 
  JOIN category ON items.category <=> category.category
SET items.category_id = category.id;
```

You may have to change some columns names, but hopefully they are obvious.

Repeat this for subcategory and any other fields.

Note: `<=>` is NULL-safe equal, so rows with NULL values will get updated correctly